# How to stop waffles from sticking to pan?

Tags: waffle

How can I keep waffles from sticking to pan? As I grease the pan with oil before putting mixture, but the waffles stick to pan and it becomes difficult to get waffles out of pan.

Comment: What type of pan? Construction, thickness, material?

Comment: Also, what type of recipe?  Many scratch recipes have considerable fat in the batter, while many boxed mixes use much less.  Those know in the US as Belgium Waffles are almost swimming in butter and many cast iron type waffle irons with actually ladle melted butter into the iron and fry the waffle to a crisp exterior which also does not stick.  If you happen to be using a box mix or converted pancake recipe and are willing to up your fat content, it may take a different recipe to overcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the pan is properly preheated to cooking temperature before pouring the batter in. If you've oiled it, and water sizzles and skips when splashed on the pan, you should be good to go.